# How do we split this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Find the minimum value of $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{4}{e^{|x-t|}} \, dt$$ where $x\in{[0,3]}$.

I really have no idea on how to solve this integral. I started of by splitting the integral recognizing the absolute value function.
$$\int_{0}^{x}{e^{x-t}} \,dt + \int_{x}^{4}{e^{x-t}} \,dt$$

But what I don't know is, is it $$\int_{x}^{4}{e^{x-t}} \, dt \quad \textrm{or} \quad \int_{x}^{4}{e^{t-x}} \, dt$$ in the above expression. While splitting how do we know whether $(x-t)<0$ or $(x-t)>0$ when we don't have a clue on the value of $t$?

We know $x\in{[0,3]}$ but if t is smaller than the range of x, $x-t$ would always yield postive right and we will be forced to split as $$\int_{0}^{x}{e^{x-t}} \,dt + \int_{x}^{4}{e^{x-t}} \,dt$$ right?

I think I'm somewhere lagging here in conceptual clarity. Moreover after doing the right splitting, I also don't have much of an idea on how to proceed. Please advise.

Comment: "we don't have a clue on the value of t"?: that was precisely the purpose of splitting! $\forall t>x,\quad x-t<0$ hence $|x-t|=t-x.$

Comment: Yes, and compute this sum $f(x)$ for each *fixed* $x\in[0,3].$ Only after that, look for the minimum value of $f.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes thanks and I got e^x + e^(4-x) -2 and we differentiate. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Minimum without Differentiation**
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\int_0^4 e^{|x-t|} d t \text { where } x \in[0,3]\\& =\int_0^x e^{x-t} d t+\int_x^4 e^{t-x} d t \\
& =-\left[e^{x-t}\right]_0^x+\left[e^{t-x}\right]_x^4 \\
& =e^x+\frac{e^4}{e^x}-1 \\
& \geqslant 2 \sqrt{e^x \cdot \frac{e^4}{e^x}}-1\quad \textrm{ (Using }A.M.\ge G.M.) \\
& =2 e^2-1 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that its minimum value is $2e^2-1 \Leftrightarrow e^x=\frac{e^4}{e^x} \Leftrightarrow x=2 $ .